# How to reference a non-nested group of tags in XSD

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

Is there a way to refer to a group of non-nested XML tags in XSD schema, e.g.:

```
<foo>
  <a>a_val</a>
  <b>b_val</b>
  <c>c_val</c>
  <d>d_val</d>
</foo>
<bar>
   <e>e_val</e>
   <b>b_val2</b>
   <c>c_val2</c>
   <f>f_val</f>
</bar>
```

What I want to achieve is to have tags `<b>` and `<c>` extracted separately as *complexType* or *abstract* element, because the very same `<b>...</b><c>...</c>` sequence might appear elsewhere (as in this example, inside `<bar>`). Is this possible?

I have also considered defining base object, and deriving `<foo>` and `<bar>` from it. However I would prefer lighter solution if possible due to nature of the real-life data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure, but are you looking for the [xsd:group](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_group.asp) element?

Comment: That sounds right, was just on my way to look this up myself :)

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks very much!

Comment: In that case +1 for the question. Wasn't 100% sure what you meant by "_extracted_ separately"...